# Google app engine css not found/deployed

Tags: google-app-engine

I have the following app.yaml + file structure:

[image]

css files keep giving me 404:

[image]

I have tried different file structures and both static_dir and static_files in the app.yaml, nothing works...

ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the current file structure and your `app.yaml` config, your css files will have to be referenced in html relative to the `url` handler you defined: like `/css/static.css`.

With that covered, the `static_dir` has to be defined properly and relative to the location of your `app.yaml`, should be `code/public/css` and **not** `/code/public/css`. ***Note the leading slash you put there***

```
handlers:
- url: /css
  static_dir: code/public/css
```

If you want the full path though in your html, your config file will have to be tweaked slightly:

```
handlers:
- url: /code/public/css
  static_dir: code/public/css
```